# how to read content of memory address 0xfeafe000 in c?

Tags: memory-address

i have tried to read content of a memory address 0xfeafe000 and 0xfe9b000. i have used a  few techinue but unable to do so.
i have tried following codes, they are-

1.

```
unsigned int *abar = (unsigned int *) 0x0feaf000;
printf("\n %x",*abar);// got segmentation fault
```

2.

```
char txt[512];
  memcpy(txt,(char *)0xfeafe000,sizeof(txt));
  printf("%s",txt);// got segmentation fault
```

is there anather way to resolve this or any flaws in my attempts??

Comment: Why are you trying to read from a specific memory address, that might not be within your application's address space?

Answer (score 0):

The logical address in your program is mapped by the OS into an address that's valid for your process, so you have no access to an absolute address in most systems.

If you got a system with direct access to the real address space, then your first example should works, but I would suggest to make abar const in that case.